# Calculating a new Latitude & Longitude based on percentage

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to work out the best way to do the following:

> Given coordinates in decimal degress (e.g. [0.0, 0.0]), calculate a new position to "pan" to, based on a percentage.

Let's say my chosen percentage to pan by is 1, how should I cater for the case when the starting point is `[0, 0]`? Performing simple arithmetic (i.e. multiplication) would not give a correct result (because `0 * x = 0`).

For example, if I want to move from `[0, 0]` decimal degrees, 1% north, I would increase X by 90 * 0.01: i.e. latitude 0.9N.

Or to put it another way, what's the best way for me to calculate a new latitude and longitude by growing/shrinking another by a percentage, assuming within correct boundaries [-90,90] and [-180, 180]?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  How do you increase a location by a percentage?  Also a percentage increase on 0 will always equal 0, so not sure how you are thinking your position will change?  Please [edit] your question to give a bit more information about what you're trying to do and how you see it working.

Comment: Hi! I'll edit the question ASAP.

Comment: Use Paint or your sketch tool of choice to make a graphic to explain your goal. Note that scaling of angular values is inherently problematical.

Comment: Are you trying to *zoom* in/out to new *extents*?

Comment: Thanks all. Apologies for the poor question. I've updated with more information.

Comment: Having updated the question, can this be moved from "on hold"?